# Bash: properly pass from wsl parameters with spaces to a program on the win10 host

Tags: bash, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having problems passing properly in bash parameter values that include spaces and/or newlines from wsl to a program on the win10 host.

Well. it's a generic question, but it comes out of a concrete use-case.
The concrete use-case is using the host-level git binary, namely `git.exe` from within the wsl.

I know there are rather popular solutions like [wslgit](https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit), that lets you call from windows the git binary in the wsl. However, this does not only implies that your wsl would lunch for every git command if it was not already running, but it incurs a gotcha-full setup and a questionably optimizable performance footprint.
My wsl is not always on - many of my tasks do not require it, and I don't want to keep it running for git - so my options are the opposite: use from the wsl the `git.exe`, which is always present.

Anyway, I believe this represents a more generic case and can be relevant to any host-level program called from wsl.

So, in the concrete example of `git` - I needed a shim that will pass the call to the `git.exe` whenever the `git` command is called from within any of the shells of the WSL.

This can be done by replacing `/usr/bin/git` with a shim that will wire the call to `git.exe`.

So. The 1st naive implementation was:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd/git.exe $@
```

The naive implementation worked almost well - up to the point where argument contained whitespaces and/or quotes (e.g. `git commit -m "a human comment with \"important\" hints"`). Then it went bananas.

So the next step was using `"$@"` instead of just `$@`, and nothing worked because `git.exe` hears `"commit"` instead of `commit`, and refuses to cooperate.
So I tried to skip wrapping the 1st arg. Now `git stash list` did not know what `"list"` means, because it expects `list`.
So I went around all the other forms for no avail.

I even tried going in a loop and wrap with quote marks only arguments that contain spaces (and escape any quote marks the user provided intentionally as part of her value) - so, yea - a rabbit hole - and could not get a setup that is working.

After not cracking it for days I admitted defeat - I just don't understand bash well enough to crack this one (or wsl-win-bash relations), so I fell back to the following solution - which works for me, but is less than ideal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('child_process').spawn(
  `git.exe`,
   process.argv.slice(2),
   { stdio: [0, 1, 2 ] },
);
```

The problem is that this solution is dependent on implementation details of *MY* workspace: `nodejs`. :P

I need your help to take it to the next level.

#### It would be better if I knew of a generic solution that relays on `sh`/`bash`, or whatever is available out-of-the-box on any linux available for WSL.

Comment: I get not wanting to fire up wsl just for one command, but if it's already up, why not use the git you've got right there?

Comment: @jthill so I should have two different solutions for working in `cmd.exe`, one for when wsl is up, and one for when it's not? :P

Comment: I'm not confident enough that this is your issue to state so, but if I'm understanding the problem correctly I think this is being tracked as an open issue under [Microsoft/WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2835). I don't often work with WSL and usually when I do it's because I'm checking the expected output of a \*nix command without needing to request or maintain a virtual Linux instance for a trivial purpose. If I'm understanding that issue as well, it seems the issue might be dependent on how specific programs process arguments.

Comment: You're already in bash, ... oh. this is the non-wsl bash? I get it now.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, someone suggested a sort of workaround here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2835#issuecomment-364296591. Not sure how viable this is for your use case but setting the PATH to include the directory git is housed in is a generic solution not bound to nodejs or your workspace configuration.

Comment: @jthill I still don't get it :-).  The question says, "I needed a shim that will pass the call to the `git.exe` whenever the git command is called from within any of the shells **of the WSL.**"  Based on that, it sounds like this is being called from within WSL, so I'm still confused on why Linux/WSL `git` wouldn't be used when in WSL, and `git.exe` used when in CMD.  Is it the performance of WSL2 when dealing with multiple small files on Windows filesystems?

Comment: I'm confused too. After re-reading I understand the problem, and the issue presented in the Github issue, but I can't reproduce it. If from WSL I `cd` to a git working copy under `/mnt/c` somewhere, testing your scenario with spaces and quotes works fine: `/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin/git.exe commit -m "This commit has some spaces \"and quotes\""`. Since that issue does state this happens because of how `WSL/bash` ships arguments to `exe` files, and also due to how the `exe` may process arguments, I'm wondering if this is due to the `git` implementation you've used on Windows.

Comment: @Bender the Greatest - your test works. The problem appears only when I tried to replace `/usr/bin/git` with the shim that will call the same command for us - then it goes wierd. However - the link you gave is the answer.  I still don't know what @ means, and why it plays well with bash / cmd - but it does work :)

Comment: I guess I'm still not understanding why you can't just call the Windows git binary as a matter of standard since WSL implies a presence of Windows. The use of a shim seems unnecessary here.

Comment: @RadagasttheBrown `$@` is a special bash variable that expands all positional arguments to the current command as separate words. The way you made it work in your answer works somewhat similarly to splatting positional arguments with `@args` in PowerShell to another command, if you are familiar with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative that works for me instead of a shim:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git_linux
sudo ln -s "$(command -v git.exe)" /usr/bin/git
```

This assumes that `git.exe` is in the path when creating the link (which it should be, given defaults).  If it's not, just replace the `$(command -v git.exe)` with the fully qualified path to `git.exe`.

Passing in strings with escaped quotes and spaces works this way as well.

Comment: I feel like I'm out of the loop here on why a shim or symbolic link to the Windows binary is required in the first place. The Windows executable is able to be invoked directly from WSL. No matter how I look at it the shim is unnecessary so I'm assuming I'm missing something.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I agree with you overall.  I wouldn't do it.  The only reason I could see this being "logical" would be (a) the user wants to avoid typing out the `.exe` when in WSL, and (b) the Windows binary is needed to avoid the known WSL2 performance issues on Windows filesystems.

Comment: I hope it's not the first reason, this is way overengineering over typing four extra characters lol. I could only see the second issue being valid if a `bash` script is expected to run on both `WSL` and a native Linux installation, but even then I guess I would check `/proc/version` and if WSL, use the `git` binary under the windows path, if anything else, just call the `git` binary installed within WSL. Guess it's a matter of preference I suppose, though neither of these are convincing arguments to use a shim to me.

Comment: If `git.exe` is in $PATH, then symbolic link is not necessary. And you can invoke directly `git` to mean `git.exe`

Comment: @Philippe Yes, that's Bender's point as well.  And that's what I would choose to do personally.  But the OP seems to want to just type `git` to call `git.exe`.  Both a shim and a symlink are probably overkill, but a symlink less so, I would think.

Comment: @Philippe Sorry, I read your comment too quickly and misunderstood you (my fault).  No - Running `git` will never automatically run `git.exe` in WSL.  You may be thinking the user is in CMD, PowerShell, or Git Bash.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - tried, works. however - you should add quote marks around `$(command -v git.exe)` as the space in `Program Files` (default installation place) foils it

Comment: @Philippe While `git` would not resolve even if the Windows' `bin` folder is on the PATH, `git.exe` should still resolve if on the PATH correct? This would be expected since \*nix never assumes a file extension to my knowledge, so you would have to include the `.exe` as when running any other file extension (e.g. `.py`, `.sh`, `.rb`, etc.). Or, will a WSL shell *never* invoke a Windows binary on the PATH even if you use the full executable name?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest As long as the Interop features haven't been disabled via `/etc/wsl.conf`, the former is correct.  (a) The full name (including the extension) of the `.exe` must be used, (b) it must either be in the Linux path and/or be called with a fully-qualified path.

Comment: So I was right, but I didn't know you could disable interop with `/etc/wsl.conf`. TIL, thank you. I don't use WSL super often, I typically use it for limited Linux command testing esp. when testing PowerShell Core scripts as I write these on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

That's the answer:

first, just for backup:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git_linux
```

then, create `/usr/bin/git` instead as:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd.exe /c @ git.exe "$@"
```

Make sure it's runnable - you might need to `chmod +x` it, I don't remember if I had to...

---

All hail  **Bender the Greatest**, who pointed out in comments the following link:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2835#issuecomment-364296591.

---

*Edited:*
checkout the solution based on a symlink by **NotTheDr01ds** (the one marked with V)

Comment: What is weird here is that I can't reproduce your issue. I can call the git binary under Program Files fine from WSL, and use arguments containing both spaces and escaped quotes, without any workaround. But glad that thread helped you find a solution. I'm still not sure why you are going through cmd.exe with a shim for this either, since WSL `bash` can natively call Windows executables (as evidenced by even calling cmd.exe).

Comment: @Bender the Greatest - I tried calling the exec directly, but something goes wrong around argument passing - and it happens only from the shim. Calling git.exe from the command line just worked - and that's why it was very frustrating. Echoing the command from the shim looked just like what I ran "manually". Something gets wrong in argument passing, and the `cmd.exe /c` seems to solve that - only if you trick it with the `@` thing described in the link you provided.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding *why* you need a shim. Your question seems to imply that you experienced some issue around quotes and spaces in args without the shim and attempted writing a shim as a workaround.

Comment: aha, so no. calling `git.exe` from the wsl shell works and parameters pass correctly. I wanted to be compatible with the world - i.e to call `git` and not `git.exe` , and the problem was in the shim itself as without the `cmd /c` AND the `@` params were not wired correctly. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also going to post this as an answer. I'm unable to reproduce this issue, calling a Windows-installed `git.exe` binary from WSL with both spaces and escaped quotes from `bash` within WSL seems to work fine, provided you escape the requires special characters in the binary path either with a backslash `\` or double-quote `"`:

```sh
cd /mnt/c/some/working/gitrepo

# With backslashes in the binary path
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin/git.exe commit -m "This commit has some spaces \"and quotes\""

# Quoting the binary path due to spaces
"/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe" commit -m "This commit has some spaces \"and quotes\""
```

Adding `/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/bin/` to the `PATH` variable in `bash` should also work so you don't have to utilize a fully-qualified name to the binary.

I did not need to create a shim or do anything else special other than make sure the path to the `git.exe` binary was escaped properly.

> **Note:** This is a guess and not a claim (I will remove this if disproven) but my suspicion here is that OP is using a Git binary for Windows that just isn't as compatible with direct invocation as the version I'm using. It may not even be specific to a Git version, but resultant of how it was built for a Windows target in the first place. Read on for how I arrived at this hypothesis.

---

Some background: This issue does not affect *all* `exe` files run from WSL. According to this [Microsoft/WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2835) issue, this isn't so much a "bug" as it is due to the way WSL/`bash` ships arguments to Windows executables, coupled with how certain programs actually process command line input. This solution won't work for all binaries, and OP's answer may not work for all binaries either. This sort of inconsistency is unfortunate, but not uncommon, when working with two runtimes in tandem.

The linked issue seems to call for documentation to be added/updated so developers and operators can better understand how WSL actually passes arguments to native Windows' executables.

Comment: the goal is to fit with other tools like a suite of scripts and aliases shared with mac users in the team that call `git`, and should get `git.exe`. Check the symlink solution  - worked as well, and that saves one invocation layer :D donno why I didn't try it in the first place <silly-grin>

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, the system call that starts a program requires, and passes, what humans understand as the command line options and arguments as individual strings: if a unix command line is `git commit -m "Initial commit"`, the argument strings the shell passes to the Unix `execve` system call, and received by the started program, will be `git`, `commit`, `-m` and `Initial commit`.

On Windows, the system call that starts a program requires, and passes, a single string argument: the undigested command line. [Microsoft's runtime supplies a default utility often linked in to built programs that scans that command line to break it out into separate arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-160#parsing-c-command-line-arguments), which are then passed in to whatever equivalent of `main` the programming language has, and that's why command lines on Windows often follow those quoting and escape handling conventions.

So: when you use a Unix shell to start a program, Windows or not, the shell will scan the command line into the program name and its arguments, after processing any program-specific variable assignments and I/O rewiring; it will then hunt down the program file that runs that program and issue the `execve` system call to run it with the scanned arguments and environment.

But if the invoked program's loader is for a Windows program, it knows the target is not set up to receive parsed argument strings: it's expecting an undigested command line. So the windows program loader in the unix-to-windows compatibility layer *has to reconstruct a command line the windows program will parse into the provided arguments*.

And that's where you're getting bit: you (eventually) did

```
/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd/git.exe "$@"
```

and bash passed the program path followed by the arguments you gave as the strings `commit`, `-m` and `a human comment with "important" hints`. Since that `.exe` is a windows program, the Windows program loader fires it up, and has to reconstruct a command line that the receiving program will scan to identify those same arguments . . . without any way to know how it will do that.

It seems the shim does rely on programs using the double-quoted string convention, but does not rely on programs processing internal escapes, so it doesn't add them to the quotes around `"important"` when reconstructing the command line.

You have to do it. Since you're using bash, that means getting bash to do it for you.

You can *probably* use

```
/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd/git.exe commit -m 'A human comment with \"important\" hints'
```

but you'll have to try it to be sure. That command line is parsed by the shell into `/c/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe`, `commit`, `-m` and `A human comment with \"important\" hints` after all quote processing; if the windows program loader shim Microsoft supplies just pastes them back together slapping double quotes around anything with embedded white space, that'll work.

If the shim doesn't even do that much, use

```
/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd/git.exe commit -m '"A human comment with \"important\" hints"'
```

instead.

Then, of course, you have to somehow convince `bash` to apply the proper transformations to any arguments you want to pass along. For the default scanner, which I believe `git.exe` uses, you could

```
/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd/git.exe "${@//\"/\"\"}"
```

to get the double quotes escaped in a way it'll recognize.

Comment: you go down the same rabbit hole I went and got lost. check the solution with the symlink - that's even better :)

Answer (score 0):

I got notepad++ residing in Program Files folder to work only using single quotes embedded in double quoted path:

```
alias npp="/mnt/c/'Program Files'/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```